# How to get the ID of a selected <li> or <a> with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<li class="nav" id="1"><a href="#detail">a</a></li>
<li class="nav" id="2"><a href="#detail">b</a></li>
<li class="nav" id="3"><a href="#detail">c</a></li>
```

Now I want to use jQuery to save the id (1,2 or 3) which was clicked.
How to do this?

Comment: omitting for a while that those ID are not valid, where do you want to "save" the id? have you an event handler already defined somewhere? have you already made a search? is this a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451785/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-clicked-element-using-jquery

Comment: correct link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545341/jquery-get-the-id-value-of-li-after-click-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following (jQuery 1.7 and above)

```
$('li.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  ...
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VKpRY/

jQuery 1.6 and earlier

```
$('li.nav a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").on('click',function (ee) {
ee.preventDefault();
alert($(this).parents("li:first").attr("id"));

})
```

Answer (score 0):

For each selected jQuery object, simply use `.attr('id');`. Example follows:

```
$('li.nav').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Hope this helps,

Pete